# "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by sinal11:SIGSEGV)" and "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast"

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to run the android studio by ubuntu 18.04
I have a slight problem here when trying to open the emulator

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by sinal11:SIGSEGV)
Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: The error message suggests that a driver that should exist and be loaded actually isn't. Have you tried re-installing the `swrast` driver it's complaining about? I'm not sure where the `swrast` OpenGL driver is supposed to come from or what brand of GPU would use it. It may be helpful if you provide some info about your PC, such as GPU manufacturer, etc.

Comment: Ack, I focused on the error message and missed the fact that it's the *emulator* that's having the error, not Ubuntu itself. (No wonder I found that driver name odd.) In any case, it would seem like there're some emulator packages that you may need to install. What I said is still true though: A driver that's expected to be there, isn't.